# Automate the writing records from csv to shapefile using pyshp module

Tags: shapefile, csv, pyshp

I have the following data in a csv file('file.csv')

> Date_Time,Latitude,Longitude,Wind_Speed,Status
>
> 09-10-2013/1130,13,93,50-60 gusting to 70,Observed
>
> 09-10-2013/2330,13.501,92.501,70-80 gusting to 90,Observed

I am able to convert the above data into a point shapefile using the **pyshp** module with the following code

```
import csv, shapefile
point = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)    
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     header = csvreader.fieldnames
     for field in header:
         points.field(field) ## I could define the fields on the go in a loop
         for row in csvreader:
            parts.append([(float(row['Longitude'])), float(row['Latitude'])])
            points.point((float(row['Longitude'])),float(row['Latitude']))
            points.record(row['Date_Time'], row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'], row['Wind_Speed'], row['Status'])
            # for writing records each record has to be specified
points.save('points')
```

I would like to automate the record part i.e., **point.record(row['Longitude'], row['Latitude'], row['Date_Time'],...** so if the no.of fields are more writing each field name in "point.record(...)" can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you are getting fields and records of CSV file through csv.DictReader, which is going to be the fields and records of DBF file. It gives you great flexibility and the best way to utilise this variable is to use both creating fields (be aware using default type and length here as you did) and saving the records as given below:

```
import csv, shapefile
points = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
with open("file.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     header = csvreader.fieldnames
     [points.field(field) for field in header] #The first trick
     for row in csvreader:
        #parts.append([(float(row['Longitude'])), float(row['Latitude'])])
        points.point((float(row['Longitude'])),float(row['Latitude']))
        points.record(*tuple([row[f] for f in header])) #The second trick
points.save('points')
```