# Create shapefile from file.csv using python pyshp module

Tags: python, shapefile, csv, indexing

I followed the guide given here [Automate the writing records from csv to shapefile using pyshp module](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209134/automate-the-writing-records-from-csv-to-shapefile-using-pyshp-module/265411#265411). I follow this procedure and the code doesn't give me any error, but it doesn't produce any output. What can I do to get an output file.shp to load in QGIS?
My example file.csv is:

```
y,x,day1,day2,day3
37.0925854357,14.3860984446,0.0000079572,0.0000939491,0.0000028935
37.0978554286,14.5199850398,0.0000041594,0.0000821038,0.0000015805
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
import csv, shapefile
points = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
with open("/path/to/file.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     header = csvreader.fieldnames
     [points.field(field) for field in header]
     for row in csvreader:
        points.point((float(row['y'])),float(row['x']))
        points.record(*tuple([row[f] for f in header]))
points.save('points')
```

Comment: So you're not getting any errors. What have you tried already to get it to load in QGIS? What happens when you try to load the shapefile?

Comment: @PhilippNagel the code runs but does not produce any output.

Comment: Have you searched your whole file system for a file named 'points'? Because it looks like this code might be writing to a file named 'points' in whatever directory you're running this code in.

Comment: @PhilippNagel Sorry, I found it. Is there a way to change destination path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it seems the issue was that the file was being output to an unknown location. To remedy this, modify the code as below to specify the output location.

For example, if you want to save the file to C:\Users\DF\points.shp (Windows), your last line should be:

```
points.save(r'C:\Users\DF\points')
```

Or on Linux:

```
points.save(r'/home/DF/points')
```

Comment: Sorry, my initial answer added .shp to the filename, which should not be there and will cause an error. Try the above code samples.

Comment: I did it (on Linux): **points.save(r'/home/DF/points.shp')**. It works, thank you